# How to display acts_as_taggable tags on a page with the posts underneath each tag in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using the gem [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on). I have it setup and working correctly. I am trying to create a page that lists all the tags with the posts underneath each tag they belong to?

**(Tag 1)**

- Post tagged with tag 1
- Post tagged with tag 1
- Post tagged with tag 1

**(Tag 2)**

- Post tagged with tag 2
- Post tagged with tag 2
- Post tagged with tag 2

**(Tag 3)**

- Post tagged with tag 3
- Post tagged with tag 3
- Post tagged with tag 3

Here is my code i have all the tags showing on one page but i can't get the posts to show underneath the tag?

**Tags Controller:**

```
def index
    @tag   = current_user.owned_tags
    @posts = current_user.posts.tagged_with(@tag.name)
end
```

**Tags Index View:**

```
<div class="tag-lists">
    <% @tag.each do |tag| %>

        <div><%= tag.name %></div>

        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <div><%= post.title %></div>
        <% end %>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate each one of the posts per tag

on your controller:

```
def index
    @user  = current_user
    @tags  = @user.owned_tags
end
```

on your view:

```
<div class="tag-lists">
    <% @tags.each do |tag| %>

        <div><%= tag.name %></div>

        <% @user.posts.tagged_with(tag.name).each do |post| %>
          <div><%= post.title %></div>
        <% end %>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I get no errors but i only get a list of tags their aren't any posts underneath them.

Comment: Can you check the source code of the page when you request it from your browser and check if any div is written?

Comment: No there is no div being written. Just the div with tags.

Comment: Weird, go into the rails console and try the following with any user that you know that has at least one post with one tag:
`user = User.find(user_id_you_already_know)`
`tag = Tag.find(tag_id_you_already_know)`
`posts = user.posts.tagged_with(tag.name)`
and verify if you get any post, you should since you are asking for all the posts created by the user with that specific tag

Comment: Yes that works i get the posts associated with the tag.

Comment: Then I'm not sure why the view code I gave you is not working, it should. Replace `<div><%= post.title %><div>` with `<%= debug(post) %>` and check the output and try to debug, but the code I gave you is mainly the same code you did run on the console, it iterates each tag and per each tag it iterates each post

Comment: Yeah it doesn't make sense. It's like it doesn't even recognize the code.

Comment: Ok i fixed you forgot to put a .each at the end of @user.posts.tagged_with(tag.name). So it should be @user.posts.tagged_with(tag.name).each do |post|. If you change your answer i will accept it.